# Two split environments have different indents

Tags: indentation, alignment, split

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \sin(B\hat{A}M) & =2\sin(15)\sin\left(135-B\hat{A}M\right)\\
                            & =2\sin(15)\left(\sin(135)\cos\left(B\hat{A}M\right)-\cos(135)\sin\left(B\hat{A}M\right)\right)
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
    %
    \noindent
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \tan(B\hat{A}M) & =\sin(15)\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\tan\left(B\hat{A}M\right)\right)\\
                            & =\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(15)}{\sqrt{2}\sin(15)+1}\\
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

So I tried \noindent and %, but I can't seem to get the two equations to align up. I recognise that there are probably better ways than two split environments to achieve the result, so feel free to mention them. However, I would like to know where I went wrong in my indenting for future reference.
[image]

Comment: Well, just use a single ((split) equation* environment.

Comment: the split environment is centred by the equation if you want it left aligned to a fixed indent, use the  `fleqn` package option

Comment: there is no reason to use split here, you could replace the `equation*` by `align*` then you don't need a nested environment

Comment: Off-topic: Have you considered writing `\widehat{BAM}` instead of `B\hat{A}M`?

Comment: @Mico I didn't know that was a convention for angles

Comment: all your (...) would look a lot better without `\left\right` which is making them over large because of the accent

Comment: @David Calisle. That was intentional. Maybe it's because I moved from word, but I like my brackets to encompass everything inside them

Comment: @yolo but it looked wrong just looking at the image, before I checked the markup, so I don't advise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo are using a centred `equation*` so each of the `split` environments is centred see the marked spaces

[image]

Here I think you just want a single `align*`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \noindent X\dotfill X
    \begin{align*}
            \sin(B\hat{A}M) & =2\sin(15)\sin\left(135-B\hat{A}M\right)\\
                            & =2\sin(15)\left(\sin(135)\cos\left(B\hat{A}M\right)-\cos(135)\sin\left(B\hat{A}M\right)\right)
\\[\jot]
            \tan(B\hat{A}M) & =\sin(15)\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\tan\left(B\hat{A}M\right)\right)\\
                            & =\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(15)}{\sqrt{2}\sin(15)+1}\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I might be tempted to eliminate most (all?) `\left` and `\right` directives, though. And the final row needn't be terminated with a double-backslash.

Comment: @Mico perhaps yes although I more or less intentionally kept the interior markup unchanged here as it wasn't too bad and wasn't related to the alignment question